# Does UIDocumentSaveForCreating close the document after creation?

Tags: ios, icloud, uidocument

What is the behavior of `[UIDocument saveToURL:forSaveOperation:completionHandler:]` when invoked with `UIDocumentSaveForCreating`?

---

### Approach#1 - saveToURL: closes the document after save

Then no need to close the document.

```
MYDocument *document = [[MYDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:fileURL];
[document saveToURL:fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL saveSuccess) {
    if (!saveSuccess) {
        ALog(@"Failed to create file at %@", fileURL);
        failureBlock();
        return;
    }
    successBlock(fileURL);
}];
```

---

### Approach#2 - saveToURL: does not close the document after save

Then I would have to close the document myself, like this:

```
MYDocument *document = [[MYDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:fileURL];
[document saveToURL:fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL saveSuccess) {
    if (!saveSuccess) {
        ALog(@"Failed to create file at %@", fileURL);
        failureBlock();
        return;
    }
    [document closeWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL closeSuccess) {
        if(!closeSuccess) {
            ALog(@"Error during close after creating %@", fileURL);
            failureBlock();
            return;
        }
        successBlock(fileURL);
    }];
}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha realized that UIDocument has a `documentState` property.

In step1 the documentState returns `UIDocumentStateNormal`, so it is open.

In step2 the documentState returns `UIDocumentStateClosed`, so it is closed.

```
MYDocument *document = [[MYDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:fileURL];
[document saveToURL:fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL saveSuccess) {
    if (!saveSuccess) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create file at %@", fileURL);
        failureBlock();
        return;
    }
    NSLog(@"step1: documentState: %d", document.documentState);
    [document closeWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL closeSuccess) {
        if(!closeSuccess) {
            NSLog(@"Error during close after creating %@", fileURL);
            failureBlock();
            return;
        }
        NSLog(@"step2: documentState: %d", document.documentState);
        successBlock(fileURL);
    }];
}];
```

---

So **NO** is the answer my own question

> Does UIDocumentSaveForCreating close the document after creation?